# Correct syntax for SQL Submittion

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, prestashop

I'm working with Prestashop and I've got a module that generates shipping labels for my orders. When a label is made it generates a tracking code that can be used on the carriers website. The problem though is that our shippers have to copy and paste this code into prestashop for customers to receive a tracking email. It's my goal to automate this process to minimize human error within our system.

I've found the table and column within prestashop's database that houses the tracking code (ps_order_carrier, tracking_number) and I have confirmed that changing this value in the database effects the order in the way I have intended. Within the prestashop module there is a section of code that submits the tracking number and various order information like the order id which I will likely need to it's own table so I'm assuming I can just duplicate this portion of code and modify it to meet my needs. The following is the code within the module:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.$this->name.'_labels
    (
        id_order,
        id_shipment,
        postage_label_ref_id,
        postage_label_object,
        postage_label_updated_at,
        postage_label_label_url,
        tracking_code,
        selected_rate_ref_id,
        selected_rate_object,
        selected_rate_updated_at,
        selected_rate_service,
        selected_rate_carrier,
        selected_rate_shipment_ref_id,
        tracker_ref_id,
        tracker_object
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        "'.(int)$data['id_order'].'",
        "'.pSQL($data['id_shipment']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['postage_label']['ref_id']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['postage_label']['object']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['postage_label']['updated_at']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['postage_label']['label_url']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['tracking_code']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['selected_rate']['ref_id']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['selected_rate']['object']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['selected_rate']['updated_at']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['selected_rate']['service']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['selected_rate']['carrier']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['selected_rate']['shipment_ref_id']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['tracker']['ref_id']).'",
        "'.pSQL($data['tracker']['object']).'"
    )';

    Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql);
```

I made a copy of this directly underneath and amended it to meet my needs but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to. I have a feeling I'm messing up the syntax. I've tried a few different variations of it so it's a bit chaotic but here is what I have as of writing this:

```
$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO `ps_order_carrier` WHERE `id_order` = '.(int)$data['id_order'].'

    (
        tracking_number
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        "'.pSQL($data['tracking_code']).'"
    )';

    Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql2);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this would save us so much time.

Thanks!

Comment: you sure you're not wanting to do an UPDATE here? INSERT doesn't have a WHERE clause; only `INSERT ... SELECT` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` do.

Comment: unclear questions are starting to attract bad answers; you've been given (good) answers and my comment, so??

Comment: Bad answers by persons only considering the SQL tag and excluding the Prestashop one :).

Comment: My bad, should of been using Update. As soon as I saw the first response it clicked in my head. Thank you.

Comment: You should try to avoid direct SQL queries when you can deal with objects and existing methods. Prestatshop includes a complex system of hook. For example when you create a new Product Object the search module will catch this object creation and index it in its cache. but if you insert it directly in DB it will never know that this new product exist.

Comment: I'll definitely look into that but I'm a bit of a novice so it might take me a while to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to update a row using an "INSERT" query.

```
$sql2 = 'UPDATE `ps_order_carrier` SET tracking_number = "'.pSQL($data['tracking_code']).'" WHERE `id_order` = '.(int)$data['id_order'].'

Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql2);
```

But the best way would be to first load the orderCarrier Object and change its tracking value without doing a direct query to DB.

```
$order = new Order($data['id_order']);
$orderCarrier = new OrderCarrier($order->getIdOrderCarrier());
$orderCarrier->tracking_number = $data['tracking_code'];
$orderCarrier->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid all kind of mistakes in MySQL query syntax Prestashop have some classes and functions you can use:

```
Db::getInstance()->insert($this->name.'_labels', 
    array(
          'id_order' => (int)$data['id_order'], 
          'id_shipment' => pSQL($data['id_shipment']),
           /*and so on*/
    )
);
```

Remember to cast all ID values to `int` and use `pSQL` in all string values. 
There is an `update` function if you need it too.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

there is no where clause in the insert statement.

specify all the values - and you get a new record.

```
$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO ps_order_carrier
    (
        tracking_number
        , id_order
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        "'.pSQL($data['tracking_code']).'"
        , "'.(int)$data['id_order'].'"
    )';
```

- not tested - you may still need to fiddle with the quotes...

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I saw your message it clicked that I was using the wrong clause.